# Set Url.Content("~") to root of area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When writing `@Url.Content("~")` inside of an Area, I would like it to reference the root of that Area instead of the root of the application. How can I accomplish this?

For example, given the following folder structure, I would like `Url.Content("~")` to resolve to `http://localhost:52478/Admin/` instead of `http://localhost:52478/`.

- Areas

  - Admin

    - Content

      - ...
- Content

  - ...

Comment: You need to write your own helper instead of using `Url.Content` if you want to achieve that.

Comment: @Stijn I'm surprised that this hasn't been integrated into the official framework. Thanks for pointing this out.